# Update Parameter value in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Actually I have a URL like this

```
abc.com?country=india&state=haryana&city=karnal
```

I have a select option in my code like this

```
<select onchange="location=this.value;">
   <option value="">karnal</option>
   <option value="">panipat</option>
   <option value="">ambala</option>
   <option value="">kurukshetra</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to change state city parameter in URL? How can I do that?

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741834/laravel-select-onchange-update-request-query-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can set this **URL** Like this

```
Route::get('urlendpoint/{country?}/{state?}/{city?}');
```